# Get-aduser Password Expired Filter not working correctly

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Running this command gives me loads of results, as excepted.

```
Get-Aduser -Properties * -Filter {PasswordExpired -eq $false}
```

But if i run this command:

```
Get-Aduser -Properties * -Filter {PasswordExpired -eq $true}
```

I don't get any result

But when i do a `get-aduser test.user -Properties *` and look at the PasswordExpired field it says "True".

So i try it using 'True' instead of $true in the filter

```
Get-Aduser -Properties * -Filter {PasswordExpired -eq 'True'}
```

I still dont get a result.

But if i run it like this:

```
Get-Aduser -filter {enabled -eq $true -or enabled -eq $false} -Properties * | where {$_.PasswordExpired -eq $true}
```

It works and lists all the accounts with password expired. So how come it's not possible to filter "PasswordExpired -eq $true" in get-aduser but it is after a pipe?

```
    PSVersion                      4.0                                                                                                                                       
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                       
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                   
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209                                                                                                                           
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17400                                                                                                                            
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}                                                                                                                      
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the cmdlet itself does not create in internal object[property] for `PasswordExpired`. $_.PasswordExpired is a method, not a static property so it has to be called when its filled. Because of the (slow) speed of big queries (with that number of properties), the -Filter was implemented to reduce the output-calls, not the same way as the object[property] pipeline.

So you have to a) filter the objects as they become one in the pipe (I would recommend this, I just filter almost everything in [filter-]pipes) or b) filter the text output (select-string).

The 'correct' way then would be the way you just did it:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter * | `
   # to get the whole object(s), most simple way
   # You can make the query faster here, by getting less properties
   #   -Properties Name,PasswordExpired -Filter *
? { $_.PasswordExpired -eq $false } | `
   # here it became an $_.property,
   # just filter what you need from the object stream
ft Name,PasswordExpired
   # do some output
```

In most cases I personally use | select-object FOO | Out-GridView, so nothing gets hidden and I can sort/search the resultset afterwards.

Comment: But then how comes it works with $false?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a glitch in the cmdLet. There is no direct attribute to indicate the expired state of the password. So while it seems like a simple question, there are several moving pieces to determine the state. Each account does have a property of the date the password was last changed. You can run your own query that will be more efficient and not put so much load on your LDAP servers.

```
$pwAge = 30 # adjust this as needed to match your domain password policy
$oldPassDate = ((get-date).adddays(-$pwAge)).ToFileTimeUtc()

# Ldap notes
# ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE 0x0002  2
# ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD 0x10000 65536
# Ldap bitwise AND = 803
# Ldap bitwise OR = 804

# This Ldap query asks for:
# User objects that last set their password at least 30 days ago
# and do not have "password never expires" or the disabled flags set
get-adobject -ldapFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(pwdlastset<=$oldPassDate)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.804:=65538))"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$users= get-aduser -properties DisplayName,Name,PasswordExpired -Filter {Enabled -eq $true}
$users|where {$_.PasswordExpired -eq "True"}|Export-Csv c:\ExpiredPasswordUsers.csv -NoClobber -NoT
```